# Tradingview custom function with security()

Tags: function, pine-script

I'm looking at the Pine version 3 migration guide and there's an example showing a custom function and using security() to call that function. https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Pine_Version_3_Migration_Guide

Now I tried to change my custom function in order to return two values instead of one, but for some reason it doesn't work anymore. The error is on line 10 ("[t,i] = ...") and says: *variableType.itemType is not a function*.

My code below, can anyone advise what the issue is please?

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")

calcS() =>
    s = 0.0
    j = 0.0
    s := close + 1
    j := close + 2
    [s, j]
[t, i] = security(tickerid, '120', calcS())
plot(t, color=red, transp=0)
plot(i, color=blue, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem. You can't return tuple from security. It's in our plans to fix this bug.

Now you may use the following workaround:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")

calcS() =>
    s = 0.0
    j = 0.0
    s := close + 1
    j := close + 2
    [s, j]

calcSs() =>
    [s, j] = calcS()
    s

calcSj() =>
    [s, j] = calcS()
    j

t = security(tickerid, '120', calcSs())
i = security(tickerid, '120', calcSj())
plot(t, color=red, transp=0)
plot(i, color=blue, transp=0)
```

Comment: i have similar issue plt_calc_val(V2, open_open,close_close) =>
    plot1 = V2 ? open_open >close_close 4 or 
                     open_open == close_close ? 1 : 0
    [plotc1]
[plotc1] = plt_calc_val(plt_calc_val(V2, open_open,close_close) 

//testingthis = 0
testingthis = security(syminfo.tickerid, "45", plotc1, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)

Error:
cannot use a mutable variable as an argument of the security function. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Starting with Pine v4 you can use functions returning tuples with `security()`:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
f() => [open, high]
[o, h] = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", f())
plot(o)
plot(h)
```